# Filter two arrays using the properties in Reactjs

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and want to filter the  array from another using reactjs.
I want to display only `checked=true` and the `value` property in first array is equal to the `listname` in second array.

can anyone help to provide the sample code to do that?

### Firstarray:

```
[
  {
    "listname": "Cash Deposit",
    "totalsuccess": "45"
  },
  {
    "listname": "Cash Withdrawl",
    "totalsuccess": "25"
  },
  {
    "listname": "Fund Transfer",
    "totalsuccess": "9"
  }
]
```

### Second array:

```
[
      {
        "name": "txn",
        "value": "Cash Deposit",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "txn",
        "value": "Cash Withdrawl",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Array.prototype.filter + Array.prototype.some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `filter` with `some`

```js
const a = [
      {
        "name": "txn",
        "value": "Cash Deposit",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "txn",
        "value": "Cash Withdrawl",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]

const b = [
  {
    "listname": "Cash Deposit",
    "totalsuccess": "45"
  },
  {
    "listname": "Cash Withdrawl",
    "totalsuccess": "25"
  },
  {
    "listname": "Fund Transfer",
    "totalsuccess": "9"
  }
]

const res = a.filter(obj => {
   if(obj.checked) {
      return b.some(item => item.listname === obj.value);
   }
   return false;
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way to go about it.

```
firstArray.forEach( item => {
    secondArray.forEach( secondItem => {
       if(secondItem.checked && item.listname === secondItem.value) {
             //do your action here
         }
       })
})
```

You can use `filter` prototype, if you do not want to implement these loops manually

Hope it helps :)